# Как сделать фильтр товаров на php?

Tags: php, sql

Есть следующий фильтр:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть таблица products в БД, есть таблица product_countires (отношение М:М), где содержатся данные о стране-производителе, поскольку в букете их может быть много.

Как правильно обработать данный фильтр? Какой запрос нужно сделать в БД? Т.е. нужно, помимо цены (`SELECT * FROM products WHERE price > :price_smallest AND price < price_biggest`) нужно как-то выбрать по производителю, т.е. нужно сделать join в таблицу? Но как?

Comment: ну собственно самый обычный join. раз вы знаете такое слово, то не знать как делать невозможно. ибо гугл и этот сайт по этму слову даст кучу примеров и все они элементарные

Answer (score 1):

LEFT JOIN легко с этим справляется, вместо id замени на нужный идентификатор для сравнения, можно также использовать сокращения AS

```
SELECT *
FROM products
LEFT JOIN product_countires ON products.id = product_countires.id
WHERE price.products > :price_smallest
  AND price.products < :price_biggest
  AND ...
  AND ...
```

Comment: А почему LEFT, а не обычный INNER ? если условие на страну задать в части where, то эффекта от LEFT уже не будет. А если указать в ON, то он не сработает как фильтр

Comment: Почему в where не будет эффекта?

Comment: Я не говорил, что от WHERE не будет эффекта. я сказал, что эффекта не будет от LEFT - выдавать записи из первой таблицы вне зависимости от наличия записей во второй. Если будет условие (кроме проверки на is null) в части where то left будет равнозначен inner, только запутает оптимизатор и он может принять не верный план выполнения. И так же я говорил, что если условие на страну поместить в ON и оставить left, то условие не сработает, потому что left найдет все записи вне зависимости от их наличия во второй таблице и вне зависимости от любых условий на вторую таблицу в ON

Comment: Понял в чем дело, спасибо, надо как нибудь поработать над этим, по сути посыл построения запроса верный, исходя из него можно уже составить подходящий через INNER